# scalebox or new font switch to create specific font size?

Tags: fontsize, best-practices, scalebox

I want to set a small portion of text in a font size not covered by the standard font switches and found two ways to do so:

1. Define a new font switch: `\newcommand\newfs{\fontsize{48}{60}\selectfont}`, then apply it to my text: `{\newfs This is in 48 pt.}`.
2. Use a scalebox (requires the `graphicx` package, which I need anyway): `\scalebox{5}{This is scaled up by the factor 5.}`.

What is the difference between the two, and is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: You can't have line breaks if you use scalebox and the spaces between the words can no longer stretch. Depending on the actual font the look can be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost always prefer the first form.

Your `\newfs` selects the 48pt font (or 50pt in the examples here)  as chosen by the font designer (or at least the person who set up the latex mappings for the font), and that is all it does: line breaking etc all happens as usual, using the new font.

The second form sets the text in a horizontal box, like `\mbox` with no linebreaking then supplies a graphical scale to the whole box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,graphicx}
\newcommand\newfs{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

{\newfs This is scaled up by the factor 5.

}

\scalebox{5}{This is scaled up by the factor 5.}.

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

Note that apart from the obvious fact that the second form doesn't linebreak it is using a different font. The heavier look is the 10pt body font scaled 5 times, whereas the first form uses a display font (actually a scaled version of the 17pt display font). The latin modern font family, like computer modern, has "optical scaling" with a range of fonts designed for viewing at different sizes. Typically the small fonts are heavier and wider than would be obtained by simply scaling down the 10pt font and, as here, the larger fonts have thinner strokes than are obtained by scaling the 10pt font.

The other difference is the font selection just selects a bigger font, `\scalebox` scales everything

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,graphicx}
\newcommand\newfs{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

{\newfs X\hspace{1cm}X

}

\scalebox{5}{X\hspace{1cm}X}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

With the first form having a 1cm space, but a space 5 times bigger with `\scalebox`